# How to scale database efficiently in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, scaling

I'm developing my first web application using Google App Engine Python SDK.

I know GAE handles scaling but I just want to know if I'm thinking about database design the right way.

For instance, if I have a User class that stores all usernames, hashed pw's etc., I'd imagine that once I have many users, reading from this User class would be slow.

Instead of having one giant User database, would I split it up so I have a UserA class, which stores all user info for usernames that begin with A? So I'd have a UserA class, UserB class, etc. Would this make reading/writing for users more efficient?

If I'm selling clothes on my app, instead of having one Clothing class, would I split it up by category so I have a ShirtsClothing class that only stores shirts, a PantsClothing class that stores only pants, etc?

Am I on the right track here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd imagine that once I have many users, reading from this User class
>   would be slow.

No, reading a certain number of entries takes the same time no matter how many other unread entries are around, few or a bazillion of them.

Rather, if on a given query you only need a subset of the entities' fields, consider [projection queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/projectionqueries).

"Sharding" (e.g by user initial, clothing category, and so forth) is typically not going to improve your app's scalability. One exception might perhaps come if you need queries based on more than one inequality: the datastore natively supports inequality constraints on only one field per query, and perhaps some sharding might help alleviate that. But, just like all ilks of denormalization, that's strictly application-dependent: what queries will you need to perform, with what performance constraints/goals.

For some good tips on scalability practices, consider [Google's own essays](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/overview?hl=en) on the subject.